# iphoto: deleting photos from iPhone doesn't work

Tags: iphone, photos.app, macos

Even if iPhoto tells me all the files are deleted, I can still find them on my iPhone under All Photos. There has to be a way to delete all pictures without separately selecting them on the small screen?

Image Capture does not allow me to delete anything either:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is it connected to Image Capture? Mine doesn't have the cloud icon & works as expected, over USB.

Answer (score 1):

On your phone, open the Photos app and select Albums from the bottom.  One of the albums is Recently Deleted.  Once you delete the photos from there, and sync your phone, they should all be off the phone.  The Recently Deleted album appears to work sort of like a trash can for deleted photos and videos, but with a 30 day expiration.  If a photo or video isn't recovered from Recently Deleted within 30 days, then it is removed from the phone.